# How to get list depending on condition over the relation in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a **User** and **Role** entity, with a Many-to-Many relation. In my role table I have a column named `visible` that stores a boolean value. If a user has a role (at least one amongst others) which is not visible I want to exclude him from the result set.

I can get the related roles in my query and just iterate through them and find out that way, but what I really would like to do is just have my query only return the users with all roles that are visible instead of filtering the query afterwards.

Something like :

```
public function scopeVisible($query)
{
  $query->whereHas('roles', function($q){
    // and here i want to find that thing out
  })     
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets first identify the tables we're working with

```
user
    id - integer
    name - string

role
    id - integer
    visible - bool in the form of SMALLINT 0 or 1

user_role
    user_id - integer
    role_id - integer
```

We'll solve it in plain old SQL first. Like this:

```
SELECT * FROM user 
    INNER JOIN user_role ON user_role.user_id = user.id
    INNER JOIN role ON role.id = user_role.role_id
GROUP BY user.id
HAVING COUNT(user_role.user_id) = SUM(role.visible);
```

The key here is the `HAVING` statement. We do a count on the amount of roles a user has and then we do a sum on the visible column. If all roles are visible then the amount of relations a user has to roles will equal the amount of visible roles.

Now to convert this into Laravel speak. In order to do this we'll have to use Laravel's query builder.

```
$visibleUsers = DB::table('user')
            ->join('user_role', 'user_role.user_id', '=', 'user.id')
            ->join('role', 'role.id', '=', 'user_role.role_id')
            ->groupBy('user.id')
            ->havingRaw('COUNT(`user_role`.`user_id`) = SUM(`role`.`visible`)')
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with whereHas but I would try something like this

```
public function scopeVisible($query)
{
  return $query->whereHas('roles', function($q) {
    $q->where('visible', '=', true);
  });     
}
```

And then use it: `$usersVisible = User::visible()->get();`

Comment: Well, at first I thought that too, but it's not quite the thing. User can have multiple roles, so if one of the roles he has, has visibility set to none, than I want to exclude him.